# my.cnf has no effect in MAMP 3

Tags: mysql, mamp, my.cnf

I'm trying to set the `max_allowed_packet` variable in MySQL (MAMP 3.0.6). I have created `my.cnf` in `/Applications/MAMP/conf` with the following content:

```
  [mysqld]
  max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

I have restarted MAMP but the changes refuse to pick up. PHPMyAdmin still shows `4,194,304` for "max allowed packet" in the "Variables" section.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to `my.cnf` should be `/Applications/MAMP/Library/my.cnf`.

Comment: You should self accept, considering it fixed your issue, I assume?

Comment: Yep, but there's a two-day embargo on that. Will do once it lifts.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I didn't realise :)

Answer (score 0):

For MAMP 3.4 the correct place for my.cnf appears to be */etc/my.cnf*, */etc/mysql/my.cnf*, */Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf* or *~/.my.cnf*.

According to mysqld --verbose --help

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```